# User's non-command answer in Telegram Bot getting as PM

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a python Telegram bot and I would like create a command where the Bot asks a question to the User and the Bot should send me the answer as PM. Now I would like to know how I can get the answer / a non-command message?

```
def Command(bot, update):
bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="How are you?")
bot.send.message(chat_id= <MY CHAT_ID>, text=update.message.text)
```

I tried it like this but now the Bot is sending me '/Command input' and not the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with this example:
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot2.py